# Facebook PHP SDK not getting valid Access Token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been following along with the instructions in the developers docs and have run into a problem when for the PHP-SDK tutorials.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

The "Get the User's profile via the Graph API and print their name" example at the above URL seems to break during the Try, as near as I can tell it's receiving a bad Access Token.

Error Message:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in myURL/sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1254

I can get a valid access token through FQL queries successfully, but am only getting error messages when using the PHP SDK command $facebook->api('/me','GET') (as the docs and tutorial show) and from what I can tell it should be getting a valid access token on the fly but isn't.

Is there something that I'm missing from somewhere else that I'm meant to be using in this example? I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

[EDITED TO SHOW CODE]

```
<?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the user logged in to your application? You can get a url to log them in from $facebook->getLoginUrl();

Comment: Thats the kicker, I'm the user, I'm logged in to Facebook, and the app has permission with my account already, the `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();` actually gets my User ID number, but it all breaks down when it tries to get an Access Token. Editting my entry to show my code as it is.

Comment: I inserted `echo "<pre>".$e."</pre>";` after the catch to show the above error message.

Comment: Being logged in to Facebook is fine – but a server-side app won’t notice this until you go through the login flow to get a fresh access token.

Comment: Moreover your code `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];` is outside the `if` block which might show the error you are getting if the User is not available.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena - That was put there on purpose for testing.

Comment: @CBroe - Thats the problem, the fresh Access Token is being rejected with that error message.

Comment: Get the `getAccessToken` call out of there – it might return an _app_ access token. Calling `getUser` is normally enough to have the SDK set a user access token (if available) internally.

Comment: @CBroe - also put in for testing purposes, just to see if I could get an access code, removed that and the `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];` that was outside of the if statement with no effect.

Comment: The error as near as I can tell is happening during `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');`, because the Try is kicking back that exception.

Comment: @CBroe - I've edited the script to reflect what is presented by Facebooks example.

Answer (score 0):

Alright never mind, for some odd reason, after no changes for 24 hours, this script is working.
Thanks for all the help any way folks :)